# If I have a Article model, should I create functions to clean the title in the model? How to test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Just starting out here, I have a Article.rb model that stores articles.

So it has the article_body, title, etc. as properties.

I need to clean the title for bad characters, should I create a function that takes the title and returns the cleaned up title string in the Article.rb model?

I want to write a rpsec test for this also, preferrable TDD style so I need some guidance.

I have so far:

```
describle Article do

before(:each) do
  a = Article.new
end


 it 'should remove any commas from the title' do


 end



end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to take advantage of [model callbacks such as before_save.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

before_save :strip_commas

  def strip_commas
    self.title.gsub!(",", "")
  end

end
```

This will strip the commas before the save.

You would then want to do something like:

```
describle Article do

before(:each) do
  article = Article.new(:title => "My title")
end


 it 'should remove any commas from the title' do
    article.title = "My title, contains, commas"
    article.save
    article.title.should eq("My title contains commas")
 end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
describle Article do

before(:each) do
  article = Article.new(:title => " variables , methods , instances") 
end


 it 'should remove any commas from the title' do
    article.your_method
    article.title.index(',').should be_nil
 end



end
```